# Problema sobre guardar descargas de videos en una carpeta

Tags: python, revisión-de-código, video, descarga

mi consulta es sobre un código que busca automatizar la descarga de todos los videos de un canal de YouTube, si bien PyCharm no me genera errores de código, pero al correrlo, no se guarda en la carpeta donde coloqué que se guarde. Alguien me podría ayudar por favor?

Si bien en el PowerShell no genera errores, en el terminal local me aparece la siguiente imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from time import sleep
    import time
    from random import randint
    import requests
    from pytube import YouTube
    # Open browser
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    # My youtube channel

    #aquí colocaré el link del canal
    url = "(link del canal)"

    #Get youtube video
    def get_video_youtube(driver,url):
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(randint(5, 9))
        driver.get(url+"/videos")

        ht = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")

        while True:
            prev_ht = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(2)
            ht = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")

  

            if (prev_ht == ht):
                break
            links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='video-title']")
            #supuestamente aquí está el problema, ya que no guarda ni escribe en el archivo txt
            with open("D:\somefile.txt", 'w') as the_file:
      
                for link in links:
                    print(link.get_attribute("title"))
                    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
                    yt = YouTube(link.get_attribute("href"))
                    hd = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
                    hd.download("D:\youtube1")
                    the_file.writelines(link.get_attribute("href")+'\n')
                    sleep(3)

    get_video_youtube(driver, url)
```